# mySQL query for empty and NULL value together

Tags: mysql, sql

In a database, among the fields, I have two fields which are `picName` and `UserName`.
The `picName` can have a `NULL` value, a picture's name or it can be **empty**.

I want to query the `userName` of those entries whose `picName` is either `NULL` or **empty**.

I tried these commands separately

```
Select userName from user where picName = ''

Select userName from user where picName IS NULL
```

But I want to get both the results in 1 query.

I tried using `IN` operator like this

```
Select userName from user where picName IN ('' , IS NULL)
```

But it didn't work.

How should I do it...?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use `OR` if you have multiple filters in your condition

```
Select userName 
from user 
where picName IS NULL OR 
      picName = ''
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the other answers is to use MySQL's [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) or [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) functions:

```
SELECT userName FROM user WHERE IFNULL(picName='',TRUE);
SELECT userName FROM user WHERE COALESCE(picName,'') = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You want one of both conditions to be satisfied, so condition one `OR` condition two must be true, and that's exactly what you need to write:

```
Select userName from user where picName = '' OR picName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userName FROM `user` WHERE picName IS NULL OR picName = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

...ISNULL(picName ,'') is a function of **MSSQL**

**select case when (picname is null or
                  picname = '' then username else 'filled' end 
from user**

gives you the UserName if picname = '' or null else the text 'Filled'.
If you want to filter these ones use (like the other said): 
...where picname is null or picname = ''

Answer (score 0):

Solution that checks for both empty and NULL values.

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(table.column, ''), table.fallback)
```

So your query will be:

```
SELECT userName FROM user WHERE NULLIF(picName, '') IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select userName from user WHERE ISNULL(picName ,'') = ''
```